# Possible to learn and process audio using Tensorflow?

Tags: audio, neural-network, tensorflow, signal-processing, audio-processing

I'm just starting to look into Deep Learning for an idea I have for a project. I'm very new to it and have a general question I hope someone can answer for me before I start down what is undoubtedly going to be a long dark path.

If I provide the NN (for example ) 1000 unprocessed audio files and then 1000 processed audio files (the same files but processed in a specific way)

could it generate an algorithm that I could then provide a new unprocessed audio file - and it, in turn, attempts to generate the processed version? or is that just some next level stuff.

Comment: you found any code example? I need the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Yes, look at the [Magenta project](https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta)